# How can you keep track of the last message you read in Azure Message recieve

Tags: azure, message, message-queue

When we receive 100 message in a queue .. How can you keep track of the last message you read?

When do i delete that message... I mean to ask when can we actually call it off in the process.

Comment: not 100% following, do you have a specify scenario? Will be good if you can give more context and describe the flow in a bit more details.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/    If you see this article in this when you you receive 100 messages in a queue.....How can you keep track of the last message you read?

When do i delete that message... I mean to ask when can we actually call it off in the process.   I hope it makes somethings clear

Comment: ok, you are using service bus, a bit clear. now what do you me "keep track of the last message". do you mean sender want to keep track of the last message or receiver keep track of the last message?

Comment: Yes  receiver wants to keep track of the last message he received  ..How?

Comment: it is a pub-sub model, only publisher will know when is the last message. unless your message actually carry a flag to indicate itself is the last message.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the message from the queue when you are ready processing the message.

```
// Get the next message
CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = queue.GetMessage();

//Process the message in less than 30 seconds

//and then delete the message
queue.DeleteMessage(retrievedMessage);
```

If you fail to process the message in 30 second or not call deletemessage, it will become visible again. You can change the timeout and how many message you take from the queue.

[storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/)